# How do you implement position-sensitive zooming inside a JScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, zooming

I am trying to implement position-sensitive zooming inside a `JScrollPane`. The `JScrollPane` contains a component with a customized `paint` that will draw itself inside whatever space it is allocated - so zooming is as easy as using a `MouseWheelListener` that resizes the inner component as required.

But I also want zooming into (or out of) a point to keep that point as central as possible within the resulting zoomed-in (or -out) view (this is what I refer to as 'position-sensitive' zooming), similar to how zooming works in google maps. I am sure this has been done many times before - does anybody know the "right" way to do it under Java Swing?. Would it be better to play with `Graphic2D`'s transformations instead of using `JScrollPanes`?

Sample code follows:

```
package test;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

private Dimension preferredSize = new Dimension(400, 400);    
private Rectangle2D[] rects = new Rectangle2D[50];

public static void main(String[] args) {        
    JFrame jf = new JFrame("test");
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.setSize(400, 400);
    jf.add(new JScrollPane(new FPanel()));
    jf.setVisible(true);
}    

public FPanel() {
    // generate rectangles with pseudo-random coords
    for (int i=0; i<rects.length; i++) {
        rects[i] = new Rectangle2D.Double(
                Math.random()*.8, Math.random()*.8, 
                Math.random()*.2, Math.random()*.2);
    }
    // mouse listener to detect scrollwheel events
    addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {
        public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
            updatePreferredSize(e.getWheelRotation(), e.getPoint());
        }
    });
}

private void updatePreferredSize(int n, Point p) {
    double d = (double) n * 1.08;
    d = (n > 0) ? 1 / d : -d;
    int w = (int) (getWidth() * d);
    int h = (int) (getHeight() * d);
    preferredSize.setSize(w, h);
    getParent().doLayout();
    // Question: how do I keep 'p' centered in the resulting view?
}

public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return preferredSize;
}

private Rectangle2D r = new Rectangle2D.Float();
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    int w = getWidth();
    int h = getHeight();
    for (Rectangle2D rect : rects) {
        r.setRect(rect.getX() * w, rect.getY() * h, 
                rect.getWidth() * w, rect.getHeight() * h);
        ((Graphics2D)g).draw(r);
    }       
  }
}
```

Comment: Added bounty to see if I can get a full answer (ideally: the code snippet that, when added above, answers the question).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tested this, seems to work...

```
private void updatePreferredSize(int n, Point p) {
    double d = (double) n * 1.08;
    d = (n > 0) ? 1 / d : -d;

    int w = (int) (getWidth() * d);
    int h = (int) (getHeight() * d);
    preferredSize.setSize(w, h);

    int offX = (int)(p.x * d) - p.x;
    int offY = (int)(p.y * d) - p.y;
    setLocation(getLocation().x-offX,getLocation().y-offY);

    getParent().doLayout();
}
```

**Update**

Here is an explanation:  the point `p` is the location of the mouse relative to the `FPanel`.  Since you are scaling the size of the panel, the location of `p` (relative to the size of the panel) will scale by the same factor.  By subtracting the current location from the scaled location, you get how much the point 'shifts' when the panel is resized.  Then it is simply a matter of shifting the panel location in the scroll pane by the same amount in the opposite direction to put `p` back under the mouse cursor.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a minor refactoring of @Kevin K's solution:

```
private void updatePreferredSize(int wheelRotation, Point stablePoint) {
    double scaleFactor = findScaleFactor(wheelRotation);
    scaleBy(scaleFactor);
    Point offset = findOffset(stablePoint, scaleFactor);
    offsetBy(offset);
    getParent().doLayout();
}

private double findScaleFactor(int wheelRotation) {
    double d = wheelRotation * 1.08;
    return (d > 0) ? 1 / d : -d;
}

private void scaleBy(double scaleFactor) {
    int w = (int) (getWidth() * scaleFactor);
    int h = (int) (getHeight() * scaleFactor);
    preferredSize.setSize(w, h);
}

private Point findOffset(Point stablePoint, double scaleFactor) {
    int x = (int) (stablePoint.x * scaleFactor) - stablePoint.x;
    int y = (int) (stablePoint.y * scaleFactor) - stablePoint.y;
    return new Point(x, y);
}

private void offsetBy(Point offset) {
    Point location = getLocation();
    setLocation(location.x - offset.x, location.y - offset.y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your MouseWheelListener also has to locate the cursor, move it to the center of the JScrollPane and adjust the xmin/ymin and xmax/ymax of the content to be viewed.

Comment: Yes, that is true - it is also what I was trying to do in the first place (the cursor is located at 'p', and adjusting those bounds correctly is what I do not know how to do).

Answer (score 1):

I think smt like this should be working...

```
private void updatePreferredSize(int n, Point p) {
    double d = (double) n * 1.08;
    d = (n > 0) ? 1 / d : -d;
    int w = (int) (getWidth() * d);
    int h = (int) (getHeight() * d);
    preferredSize.setSize(w, h);

    // Question: how do I keep 'p' centered in the resulting view?

    int parentWdt = this.getParent( ).getWidth( ) ;
    int parentHgt = this.getParent( ).getHeight( ) ;

    int newLeft = p.getLocation( ).x - ( p.x - ( parentWdt / 2 ) ) ;
    int newTop = p.getLocation( ).y - ( p.y - ( parentHgt / 2 ) ) ;
    this.setLocation( newLeft, newTop ) ;

    getParent().doLayout();
}
```

EDIT:
Changed a couple things.

Comment: Your code does not keep the point 'p' centered in the resulting view (for an example, try zooming near the bottom-right corner), even after changing `int newTop = p.y - w / 2;` to `int newTop = p.y - h / 2;`. Please test code before proposing it as an answer.

Comment: The updated code seems to zoom into the top-left corner (java 6 on XP), not into wherever the mouse pointer is pointing. I am using the same test program listed in the question.